# wrapping series of elements that don't have parents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, normally I would use the `.wrap()` approach and wrap selected elements into a parent element but I can't. I use an *RSS* feed tool that's built into my site. This rss feed tool displays the RSS feed items, but the items (title, image, discription) per feed item, doesn't have a parent to separate the other feed items from the rest. You you end up with a continuous stack rather of elements. This is an example of the feed:

```
<br><br>
<span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">blah</span>
(Fri, 26 Jan 2018) 
<br><br>

<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/7t7td0/if_you_swat_mosquitos_they_may_learn_to_avoid/"><img src="https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/eoypOMK7F7ASgmQMh4jtCk9lk0JkV5ZvgthnZI_wJU0.jpg" alt="blah" title="blah"></a>


submitted by   <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/sleekpaprika69">/u/sleekpaprika69</a>
<a href="http://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(17)31617-2">[link]</a>   <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/7t7td0/if_you_swat_mosquitos_they_may_learn_to_avoid/">[comments]</a>

<br>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/7t7td0/if_you_swat_mosquitos_they_may_learn_to_avoid/" target="_blank">&gt;&gt; Read More</a>
<br><br>
```

This one section of code, is one article (link, img, title, date, user). The next story is followed by the same structure of tagging with `<br>`.

All of the code above should be wrapped like:

```
<div id="article">
... the code above ...
</div>
```

But it isn't and i have no idea how I would wrap something like this, when there isn't really anything to specify other than `BR` tags.

Take a look for yourself: https://wiredintel.jimdo.com/

Comment: Looking at your site, aren't the RSS feed items all wrapped in a div with class rssFeed?

Comment: no that is for ALL of the feed items, the problem is each of the feed items doesn't have a parent for each one. So i can't apply css background-color for each feed item to visually separate them.

Comment: Not certain what the issue is? Are you trying to wrap the HTML at the Question within an element?

Comment: So are you looking to wrap each individual feed item (link, img, title, date, user) in a div? If so, you won't be able to use the same ID for each.

Comment: would something like this work? `$('br').slice(0,5).wrapAll('<div class="article">');`

Comment: or would this be better? 1p:nth-child(-n+5) {background: red;}
p:nth-child(5n+0) {background: red;padding:5px;}1

Comment: Why do you not adjust the settings of the "RSS feed read tool" instead of adjusting HTML after the elements are appended to the document?

Comment: im working on a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zachreynolds/rem12umh/

Comment: You **should never** wrap items with the same id. Duplicate id(s) are not valid html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rssFeedTitle").each(
function (index) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".rssFeedTitle").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='mm'></div>");
});


$(function() {

    var test = $('.rssFeed')
        .contents()
        .filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '';
        })
        .wrap('<div class="wrappedtext" />');

});
$(function() {
$('.wrappedtext:contains("subm")').css('display', 'none');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zachreynolds/rem12umh/2/